# Getting Undefined index on PHP foreach each

Tags: php, undefined, isset

I have a chunk of PHP code that is giving me an Undefined index message.

```
$order = explode(',', $ass_icon_order);

foreach($order as $function){
    $function = (isset($function) ? $function : null);
    if($function != ''){
        $css .= '.ass-sortable-li.li-'.$function.' a:hover, .ass-sortable-li.li-'.$function.'.active a { background:'.$colors[$function].' }';
        ?>
        <li id="<?php echo $function; ?>" rel="<?php echo $function; ?>" class="ass-sortable-li li-<?php echo $function; ?>">
            <?php echo '<a href="#" class="icon-bg"><i class="ass-'.$function.'"></i></a>'; ?>
        </li>
    <?php
        $count_networks++;
    }
}
```

When I run a **print_r($order)** I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => twitter
    [1] => facebook
    [2] => googleplus
    [3] => delicious
    [4] => stumbleupon
    [5] => pinterest
    [6] => linkedin
    [7] => youtube
    [8] => fblike
    [9] => fbshare
    [10] => fbtalk
    [11] => twitter_followers
    [12] => twitter_following
    [13] => twitter_tweets
    [14] => twitter_shares
    [15] => google_shares
    [16] => google_followers
    [17] => linkedin_shares
    [18] => linkedin_followers
    [19] => delicious_shares
    [20] => delicious_followers
    [21] => youtube_subscribers
    [22] => youtube_views
    [23] => dribbble
    [24] => soundcloud_followers
    [25] => soundcloud_plays
    [26] => instagram
    [27] => mailchimp
    [28] => foursquare
)
```

When I run **print_r($colors)** I get:

```
Array
(
    [fblike] => #3b5998
    [fbshare] => #3b5998
    [fbtalk] => #3b5998
    [twitter_followers] => #4ec2dc
    [twitter_following] => #4ec2dc
    [twitter_tweets] => #4ec2dc
    [twitter_shares] => #4ec2dc
    [google_shares] => #2d2d2d
    [google_followers] => #2d2d2d
    [linkedin_shares] => #006da7
    [linkedin_followers] => #006da7
    [delicious_shares] => #3271cb
    [delicious_followers] => #3271cb
    [stumbleupon] => #eb4924
    [youtube_subscribers] => #df1f1C
    [youtube_views] => #df1f1C
    [dribbble] => #f175a8
    [soundcloud_followers] => #ff4c00
    [soundcloud_plays] => #ff4c00
    [instagram] => #3b6a91
    [mailchimp] => #2C9AB7
    [foursquare] => #0732a2
    [pinterest] => #d01d15
)
```

I seem to be getting the notice from this section of code:

```
$css .= $colors[$function];
```

I have played around with adding isset, however I don't think I am doing the check correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: `$function = (isset($function) ? $function : null);` -> `$function = (isset($function) ? $function : "");` You assigned it with null not empty string

Comment: This code: `$colors[$function]` expects each element in `$order` to be a key in `$colors`, but NONE of the `$order` values you showed are present in `$colors`. You need to sanitize `$order` to make it match up with `$colors`.

Comment: Hi @JonathanKuhn, yes sorry it is defined further up in the code like this $colors = default_social_network_tab_colors(); Referring to a function I have created

Comment: Hi @mopo922, thanks for the help. So saying that, I can see that `twitter` in the `order` array doesn't match any in the `$colors` array. Should twitter in the `order` array be defined as `[0] => twitter_followers`?

Comment: Yes, I think that would get you there.

Comment: @Jason If you made the changes from my first comment also change your if statement to this: `if($function != '' && in_array($function, array_flip($colors)))`, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: @mopo922 actually it is already defined that way. I have just updated my question with the full output from the `print_r($orders)` array. The specific warning states: `undefined index twitter`, `underfined index facebook` and so on.

Comment: Right, so you need `$colors` for `twitter`, `facebook`, etc.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Rizier123, adding your code did suppress the warnings. I must not have the variables defined correctly because after adding you code I only see half the Social Networks.

Comment: @Jason So is your question now solved?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks a million to both @Rizier123 & mopo922. Arrays do my head in sometimes. Need to do a lot more reading and research on them. Thanks Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this:

(Because NULL and empty string is not the same)

```
$function = (isset($function) ? $function : null);
```

to this:

```
$function = (isset($function) ? $function : "");
                                          //^^ See here
```

Also you have to change your if statement to this, so you check if the key exists in the array:

```
if($function != '' && in_array($function, array_flip($colors))) {
                    //^^^^^^^^ Check if '$function' exists in the array as key
```